# Path expected for join when trying to query same table using left join in Spring data JPA?

Tags: java, spring-data-jpa, left-join

I'm trying to get the latest entry for each group and I got a query from this post

[GROUP BY with MAX(DATE)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3491329/group-by-with-maxdate)

and here is the query

```
SELECT t1
FROM TrainTable t1 LEFT JOIN TrainTable t2
ON (t1.Train = t2.Train AND t1.Time < t2.Time)
WHERE t2.Time IS NULL;
```

When I try to implement the same query in Spring data JPA @Query, I'm getting

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Path expected for join! [SELECT t1
FROM TrainTable t1 LEFT JOIN TrainTable t2
ON (t1.Train = t2.Train AND t1.Time < t2.Time)
WHERE t2.Time IS NULL]
```

Is there any possible way to use the same table entity in left join?

Comment: Show your @Query annotation. Are you setting the `nativeQuery` to `true`? `@Query(value = "<YOUR SQL>", nativeQuery = true)`

Comment: This is my @Query("SELECT t1
FROM TrainTable t1 LEFT JOIN TrainTable t2
ON (t1.Train = t2.Train AND t1.Time < t2.Time)
WHERE t2.Time IS NULL"). No I'm not setting nativeQuery as true

Comment: So what happens if you set it? Without setting this flag the query is treated as a JPQL, not SQL

Comment: I will get it a try now, but I would like to know, is it possible to handle this problem in JPQL? thanks

Comment: Asnwers like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9570954/4494577) make me think it is possible.